# How to configure @babel/generator with .bablerc

Tags: babeljs

I want to set babel's generator [options](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-generator) via some form of .babelrc file. I feel this should be possible, but I cannot find any examples online. All my google-ing reports back presets or plugins.

I tried this in a .babelrc.json file:

```
{
    "config": {
        "retainLines": true,
        "compact": false,
        "auxiliaryCommentBefore": "Test"
    }
}
```

But it throw the error:

```
Error: Unknown option: .config. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
```

Answer (score 0):

This options go right into the config:

```
{
    "retainLines": true,
    "compact": false,
    "auxiliaryCommentBefore": "Test"
}
```